# Workflow Field Update giving an exception Error

Tags: workflow, field-update, workflowrule

I am using the Field Update Workflow with the below scenario-

- If Length of name(Field)is Blank  - Error Message: Name length is invalid

If Length of name exceeds 35 - Error Message: Name length is invalid .

I wrote below formula in the workflow-

OR(IF(NOT(ISBLANK(Name) ) , "Name length is invalid", null)  ,
IF(VALUE(Name) >35, "Name length is invalid", null))

It's giving me an error message - Error: Incorrect parameter type for function 'OR()'. Expected Boolean, received Text

Comment: Hey @Ravina, what is it that you are trying to achieve, workflow rules are not used to throw errors. Do you want to throw errors or do you want to update a field with the errors ?

Comment: I want to update a field with an error

Comment: Hey @Ravina, in that case, below answer should work for you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your above comments, if you just want to update a field with errors and not throw errors, then you will need to use `CASE` function in your workflow instead of `IF`.

> IF function should be used to determine if expressions are true or
>   false. Returns a given value if true and another value if false.

Your formula should be

```
CASE(OR(ISBLANK(Name), LEN(Name)>35), true,"Name length is invalid", "")
```

In your question it is said that it should write an error when `Name` field is `blank` whereas in your formula you are checking for `NOT BLANK`, Updated the formula to check for `BLANK` or check if the `Name's` length is greater than 35, in both cases, it will write the same error and in rest all cases, it will update it to empty string.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need is two validation rules and not a workflow rule. You can create one validation rule to check if the name is blank and one more to check the length of it.